# Array showing as undefined, even though I am able to log it's contents

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to get data from array, but when I try to get information from it, I am getting an error that shows the array is undefined. Please check the following code for a better explanation:

```
const socketInfo = CircularJSON.stringify(socket);
console.log(socketInfo); // shows full array correctly
console.log(socketInfo.server); // says undefined, even though server object has information in it
```

Comment: You are converting your socket object to a string with the .stringify() method. strings don't usually have public properties, hence the error socketInfo.server is undefined.

Comment: What does socketInfo look like? If it is an array, you need to iterate over sockeInfo to get the values

Comment: @Daniel would you know how I can convert the socket object to a json array? I thought the CircularJSON package would do the job.

Comment: @chrisbyte it is a generic array with a lot of sub objects. What do you mean 'iterate over socketInfo to get the values'?

Comment: In your code example, `socketInfo` will be a JSON formatted string.  It will not have properties like `.server`.  What problem are you trying to solve here?  `.stringify()` converts an object into a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned in my comment that you have to iterate over the array. I do not know what "socketInfo" looks like, but if it is an array, you can do this to get the servers

```js
var socketInfo = [
  { 
   server: 'dev', 
    ip: '10.10.10.1'
  },
  { 
   server: 'staging', 
    ip: '10.10.10.2'
  },
  { 
   server: 'production', 
    ip: '10.10.10.3'
  } 
];

socketInfo.forEach(function(x) {
    console.log(x.server);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get array values after I added a JSON.parse and toString() ....

```
const socketInfo = JSON.parse(CircularJSON.stringify(socket).toString());
```

Comment: What's the point of this?  You take an object, convert it to a string, then convert it back to an object.  Why?

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right, I am a novice programmer sorry... I removed the toString() and it still works!

Comment: The `toString()` is pointless as `.stringify()` already returns a string.  It appears you don't understand what this code does.  What are you actually trying to do here?